# Location of JSP Java code that Tomcat translated

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Currently I am building web app on JSP and Servlets, and I wanted to find java code that was generated by Tomcat 8 for my JSP files, I've already searched for answer, but files don't appear in my: Tomcat8/work/Catalina/localhost directory, project is compiled successfully, anyone has idea what could be a problem?